# C# EF Linq bitwise question

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, bit-manipulation

Ok for example, I am using bitwise like such: Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, Wednesday = 4, Thursday = 8 etc...

I am using an Entity Framework class of Business.

I am using a class and passing in a value like 7 (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday).

I want to return records that match any of those days

```
    public List<Business> GetBusinesses(long daysOfWeek)
    {
         using (var c = Context())
         {
              return c.Businesses.Where(???).ToList();
         }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT

Ok, so I am attempting the following:

```
var b = new List<Business>();
var b1 = new Business(){DaysOfWeek = 3};
b.Add(b1);
var b2 = new Business() { DaysOfWeek = 2 };
b.Add(b2);
var decomposedList = new[]{1};
var l = b.Where(o => decomposedList.Any(day => day == o.DaysOfWeek)).ToList();
```

But l returns 0 results assuming in the decomposedList(1) I am looking for monday.
I created b1 to contain Monday and Tuesday.

Comment: Please don't store data this way in a *relational* database. You want to do that in object space, fine, but....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the bitwise and operator `&` to combine your desired flags with the actual flags in the database and then check for a non-zero result.

```
        var b1 = new { DaysOfWeek = 3 };
        var b2 = new { DaysOfWeek = 2 };
        var b = new[] { b1, b2 };
        var filter = 1;

        var l = b.Where(o => (filter & o.DaysOfWeek) != 0);
        foreach (var x in l)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
```

If you have an array of filter values simply combined then with an OR `|` first:

```
        var filterArray = new []{1, 4};
        var filter = filterArray.Aggregate((x, y) => x | y);
```

Comment: Ok, I like this but how do I do it if filter is an array? Ex: var filter = []{1,2}

Comment: Simply OR (`|`) the values in your array together first since you want any one of them. e.g. 1 | 2 gives 3.  You could use another .Any clause inside the Where clause too but or'ing them first is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You must decompose the long value(bitflagged enum will be better) to it's parts then pass it to `Where`

```
return c.Businesses.Where(o=> DecomposeDays(dayParam).Any(day => day==o)).ToList();
```

**EDIT:**
decompose method:

```
private static IEnumerable<byte> DecomposeDays(byte dayParam)
{
    var daysOfWeek = new List<byte> { 1, 2, 4, 6, 8 ,16};
    return daysOfWeek.Where(o => (o & dayParam) == dayParam);
}
```

Comment: I am a noob.  Could you explain how to decompose the long?

Comment: if yo can't come up with a complete solution i provide you a complete working answer

Comment: I guess I am wondering how to create the decomposed list from the long daysOfWeek property without using a switch case or something similar.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I just didn't know if there was something cleaner.

Comment: This isn't going to work with Linq to Entities - how will SQL know what to do with 'DecomposeDays'?