# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Char get_Chars(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I would like to select only the records that have the field "1" from the string `eventTriggers` (that looks something like this : "00100010" )

I've tried and succesfully done so with more than 1 calls .. but i doubt its efficient. Basically I would want something like this ... but apprently LINQ does not support this.
(`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Char get_Chars(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`)

```
     using (var service = new dB.Business.Service.BaseBusinessService<memo>())
   {
      List<memo> result = service.Repository.GetQuery().Where(p => p.ID == ID && p.eventTriggers[index] == '1').ToList();
   }
```

Any hints towards the correct solution ? Thank you !

Comment: im using a repository ... one second i will edit

Comment: It still matters what the database at the back is. Basically, if you want to be able to do this filtering at the database, you need to specify it in a form that LINQ can translate into something the database can understand. If you've got a small enough amount of data that you're happy to bring it all out of the database before filtering, just put an `.AsEnumerable()` just before `.Where()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF can't convert the char array operation into a valid query. How about

```
IEnumerable<Memo> memos
using (var service = new dB.Business.Service.BaseBusinessService<Memo>())
{
    memos = service.Repository.GetQuery()
                    .Where(p => p.ID == ID).AsEnumerable();
}

var result = memos.Where(m => m.eventTriggers[index] == '1').ToList();
```

This gets all the memos with a matching ID locally then filters on the eventTriggers array.

---

Alternatively you could convert eventTriggers into a numeric value and use a bit mask, this would probably be a much faster query.

Linq looking like this,

```
using (var service = new dB.Business.Service.BaseBusinessService<Memo>())
{
    result = service.Repository.GetQuery()
                 .Where(p => 
                         p.ID == ID
                     &&
                         m.eventTriggers & mask != 0).ToList();
}
```

---

[more exapmles here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696169/c-sharp-ef-linq-bitwise-question)

Answer (score 2):

I Had the same problem and solved It with substring.

```
ervice.Repository.GetQuery().Where(p => p.ID == ID && p.eventTriggers.Substring(index,1) == "1").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
using (var service = new dB.Business.Service.BaseBusinessService<memo>())
   {
      List<memo> result = service.Repository.GetQuery().Where(p => p.ID == ID && p.eventTriggers.Contains('1')).ToList();
   }
```