# ASP.NET - Entity Framework - Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to asp.net MVC4 and EntityFramework.

I'm getting this error when trying to add a new method to my API:

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Here's my method:

```
// GET: api/Partenaires_prestations
        [Authorize]
        [Route("api/Partenaires_prestations")]
        public List<PartenaireMapItem> GetPartenairesWithPrestations()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();

            var queryString = Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();

            var prestation = queryString.FirstOrDefault();

            return db.Partenaires
                .Where(p => p.PartenairePrestations.Any(pp => pp.Prestation.NomPrestation == prestation.Value))
                .Select(p => new PartenaireMapItem {
                    IdPartenaire = p.IdPartenaire,
                    FirstName = p.FirstName,
                    LastName = p.LastName,
                    NomComplet = p.LastName.Substring(0,1).ToUpper() + ". " + p.FirstName,
                    Type = p.Type,
                    DureeMin = 50,
                    Lat = p.Lat,
                    Lng = p.Lng,
                    ImageUrl = p.ImageUrl,
                    SeDeplace = p.SeDeplace,
                    ADomicile = p.ADomicile,

                    NoteGlobale = p.NoteClientPartenaires.Sum(x => ((double)(x.NoteAimabilite + x.NotePonctualite +
                                             x.NoteProprete + x.NoteQualite)) / 4) / p.NoteClientPartenaires.Count,
                    Prestations = new List<string>(p.PartenairePrestations.Select(y => y.Prestation.NomPrestation))
                }).ToList();
}
```

Here's my PartenaireMapItem class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Uphair.EfModel;

namespace Uphair.Api.Models.Partenaire
{
    public class PartenaireMapItem
    {
        public int IdPartenaire { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string NomComplet { get; set; }
        public double? Lat { get; set; }
        public double? Lng { get; set; }
        public PartenaireType Type { get; set; }

        public int DureeMin { get; set; }

        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

        public int SeDeplace { get; set; }

        public bool ADomicile { get; set; }

        public double NoteGlobale { get; set; }

        public ICollection<NoteClientPartenaire> Notes { get; set; }


        public List<String> Prestations { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Here's the stacktrace:

> "{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.","ExceptionType":"System.NotSupportedException","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.NewTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, NewExpression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MemberInitTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MemberInitExpression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SelectTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at Uphair.Api.Controllers.PartenairesController.GetPartenairesWithPrestations()\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"}"

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks to anyone who will take the time to read/answer my post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Char get\_Chars(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706160/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-char-get-charsint32-method-a)

Comment: @HenrikWilshusen What ? This is not even the same error...

Comment: @PierrickMartellière have you checked what the error says? Do any of the classes have constructors? What is the *actual, full* exception, including its call stack? You can get it easily using `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Do you want me to paste the stack trace ? And the classes like ```Prestations``` and ```Partenaire``` ?

Comment: All classes in EfModel have parameterless constructors

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework instantiates objects for you. To be able to do so, it expects you to have a constructor without parameters in your class. Check if your class has such a constructor (I do not see it).

Remember that you can have more than one constructor in your class.

Comment: If I understand you well, I should put a constructor without parameters in my PartenaireMapItem class ?

Comment: If that is the class you use with your entity framework as data holder than yes..

Comment: I added a parameterless ctor to my PartenaireMapItem class but nothing changed, all the other classes already have parameterless ctors... What am I missing ?

Comment: I am going to test your class, give me some time

Comment: When I only use the PartenaireMapItem class to create a DB table it gives me the message: no Key defined, this is correct on the class if you have use fluent api to do the mapping between class and DB. My assumptions are that you are much further in the project and you are able to store and retrieve induvidual objects. Am I correct? I am using EF6.0

Comment: Yup, perfectly correct. The model is correct and the API is currently working.

Comment: Can you also confirm you are using EF6 and can you past the fluent api code for your mapping. I can then use the same and see if i can reproduce.

Comment: The answer from @JustSomeDude made the exception disappear, now apparently I must activate multiple result set, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264526/entity-framework-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-connec

Comment: Excellent you can move on!

Comment: apparently according to @Stefan this was not a good solution, I'm now on this thread => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786737/asp-net-entityframework-why-my-request-fails-to-load-response-data?noredirect=1#comment90530765_51786737

Answer (score 2):

Your exception has the important details to explain the problem here:

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are **supported in LINQ to Entities**.

To use the object initializer syntax like you are doing to get the values into the `PartenaireMapItem` object, you can use the `.AsEnumerable()` method after `.Where(...)`. Using AsEnumerable() will allow you to use LINQ to Objects functionality.

```
return db.Partenaires
            .Where(p => p.PartenairePrestations.Any(pp => pp.Prestation.NomPrestation == prestation.Value))
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(p => new PartenaireMapItem {
                IdPartenaire = p.IdPartenaire,
                FirstName = p.FirstName,
                LastName = p.LastName,
                NomComplet = p.LastName.Substring(0,1).ToUpper() + ". " + p.FirstName,
                Type = p.Type,
                DureeMin = 50,
                Lat = p.Lat,
                Lng = p.Lng,
                ImageUrl = p.ImageUrl,
                SeDeplace = p.SeDeplace,
                ADomicile = p.ADomicile,

                NoteGlobale = p.NoteClientPartenaires.Sum(x => ((double)(x.NoteAimabilite + x.NotePonctualite +
                                         x.NoteProprete + x.NoteQualite)) / 4) / p.NoteClientPartenaires.Count,
                Prestations = new List<string>(p.PartenairePrestations.Select(y => y.Prestation.NomPrestation))
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Seems to work like a charm, but I'm getting another error: "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first." Any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

The exception is because here

```
Prestations = new List<string>(p.PartenairePrestations.Select(y => y.Prestation.NomPrestation))
```

you are using `List<T>` constructor with `IEnumerable<T>` *parameter*, and as the exception message indicates, LINQ to Entities allows only *parameterless* constructors, i.e. constructors without parameters.

Simply replace it with `ToList` extension method which is recognized, hence supported by EF query translator:

```
Prestations = p.PartenairePrestations.Select(y => y.Prestation.NomPrestation).ToList()
```

Comment: Tried this, but the method is not returning anymore.

Comment: This should be applied for your original L2E query from the question, right? Without `AsEnumerable()` which totally changes the execution context. And should execute single SQL which you can see if you take the LINQ query from `return …` and replace the *last* `ToList()` with `ToString()`

Comment: adding AsEnumerable after Where() made the exception disappear, but now I need to activeate Multiple Result Set, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264526/entity-framework-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-connec

Comment: Adding `AsEnumerable()`? I didn't wanted to comment the other answers, but they are totally wrong in this particular scenario. My answer covers the cause of the exception in your question and how to avoid it. It doesn't require `AsEnumerable()`. The whole idea is to execute the whole thing server side. So use the query from the question, not from the currently accepted answer, and just modify the `Prestantions = …` as shown above. The exception should disappear. Issue solved. If you have new issues, probably you should post a new question :)

Comment: You know what, actually your current issue with MARS is caused by the `AsEnumerable()` "fix", because as I said, the "fixed" query select is executing in different context (client side, LINQ to Objects), so it activates a lot of additional SQL queries due to lazy loading of navigation properties accessed, while still processing the main query, hence MARS. If you can execute the whole thing server side (by using LINQ to Entities compatible constructs) as I suggest, there won't be not supported or MARS related exceptions.