# asp.net / EntityFramework - Why does my application pool crashes?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq, iis

I'm trying to add a new method to my API.

The method's goal is to return a list of `Partenaires` having the given `Prestation` in their prestations.

When I'm calling the method by a GET request, the application pool of my API crashes. In the event logs, I have a warning called Microsoft-Windows-WAS and the linked error is:

> A process serving application pool 'UphairApi2' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '3960'. The data field contains the error number.

And the network developer tool says that it failed to load response data.

> Failed to load response data

When I'm returning `return db.Partenaires.Where(p => p.PartenairePrestations.Any(pp => pp.Prestation.NomPrestation == prestation.Value)).ToString();`, here's the returned request:

> "SELECT\r\n`Extent1`.`IdPartenaire`, \r\n`Extent1`.`FirstName`, \r\n`Extent1`.`LastName`, \r\n`Extent1`.`Email`, \r\n`Extent1`.`Password`, \r\n`Extent1`.`PasswordSalt`, \r\n`Extent1`.`Type`, \r\n`Extent1`.`Pays`, \r\n`Extent1`.`Ville`, \r\n`Extent1`.`CodePostale`, \r\n`Extent1`.`Adresse`, \r\n`Extent1`.`Lat`, \r\n`Extent1`.`Lng`, \r\n`Extent1`.`ImageUrl`, \r\n`Extent1`.`CouvertureUrl`, \r\n`Extent1`.`DateNaissance`, \r\n`Extent1`.`ADomicile`, \r\n`Extent1`.`SeDeplace`, \r\n`Extent1`.`DateAjout`, \r\n`Extent1`.`AdresseComplement`, \r\n`Extent1`.`TelMobile`, \r\n`Extent1`.`ValidationAutomatique`, \r\n`Extent1`.`NotifEmailMessage`, \r\n`Extent1`.`NotifEmailReservation`, \r\n`Extent1`.`NotifEmailPaiement`, \r\n`Extent1`.`NotifEmailNewsletter`, \r\n`Extent1`.`NotifSmsMessage`, \r\n`Extent1`.`NotifSmsReservation`, \r\n`Extent1`.`IdUserMango`, \r\n`Extent1`.`Iban`, \r\n`Extent1`.`TitulaireCompte`, \r\n`Extent1`.`IdWallet`, \r\n`Extent1`.`IdAccount`, \r\n`Extent1`.`Valide`, \r\n`Extent1`.`Son`, \r\n`Extent1`.`Push`, \r\n`Extent1`.`IdPhone`\r\nFROM `Partenaire` AS `Extent1`\r\n WHERE EXISTS(SELECT\r\n1 AS `C1`\r\nFROM `PartenairePrestation` AS `Extent2` INNER JOIN `Prestation` AS `Extent3` ON `Extent2`.`IdPrestation` = `Extent3`.`IdPrestation`\r\n WHERE (`Extent1`.`IdPartenaire` = `Extent2`.`IdPartenaire`) AND ((`Extent3`.`NomPrestation` = @p__linq__0) OR ((`Extent3`.`NomPrestation` IS  NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS  NULL))))"

And the equivalent for Mysql Workbench:

> SELECT Extent1.IdPartenaire, Extent1.FirstName, Extent1.LastName, Extent1.Email, Extent1.Password, Extent1.PasswordSalt, Extent1.Type, Extent1.Pays, Extent1.Ville, Extent1.CodePostale, Extent1.Adresse, Extent1.Lat, Extent1.Lng, Extent1.ImageUrl, Extent1.CouvertureUrl, Extent1.DateNaissance, Extent1.ADomicile, Extent1.SeDeplace, Extent1.DateAjout, Extent1.AdresseComplement, Extent1.TelMobile, Extent1.ValidationAutomatique, Extent1.NotifEmailMessage, Extent1.NotifEmailReservation, Extent1.NotifEmailPaiement, Extent1.NotifEmailNewsletter, Extent1.NotifSmsMessage, Extent1.NotifSmsReservation, Extent1.IdUserMango, Extent1.Iban, Extent1.TitulaireCompte, Extent1.IdWallet, Extent1.IdAccount, Extent1.Valide, Extent1.Son, Extent1.Push, Extent1.IdPhone FROM Partenaire AS Extent1 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 AS C1 FROM PartenairePrestation AS Extent2 INNER JOIN Prestation AS Extent3 ON Extent2.IdPrestation = Extent3.IdPrestation WHERE (Extent1.IdPartenaire = Extent2.IdPartenaire) AND ((Extent3.NomPrestation = 'Barbe')))

I tested this request in MysqlWorkbench and a set of datas is well returned.

Here's my method:

```
// GET: api/Partenaires_prestations
        [Authorize]
        [Route("api/Partenaires_prestations")]
        public List<PartenaireMapItem> GetPartenairesWithPrestations() {

            Random rnd = new Random();

            var queryString = Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();

            var prestation = queryString.FirstOrDefault();

            return db.Partenaires.Where(p => p.PartenairePrestations.Any(pp => pp.Prestation.NomPrestation == prestation.Value))
                .ToList()
                .Select(p => new PartenaireMapItem {
                    IdPartenaire = p.IdPartenaire,
                    FirstName = p.FirstName,
                    LastName = p.LastName,
                    NomComplet = p.LastName.Substring(0,1).ToUpper() + ". " + p.FirstName,
                    Type = p.Type,
                    DureeMin = 50,
                    Lat = p.Lat,
                    Lng = p.Lng,
                    ImageUrl = p.ImageUrl,
                    SeDeplace = p.SeDeplace,
                    ADomicile = p.ADomicile,

                    Notes = p.NoteClientPartenaires,
                    Prestations = p.PartenairePrestations.Select(y => y.Prestation.NomPrestation).ToList();
                }).ToList();
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Any help would be appreciated since I couldn't find another related thread on internet.

Comment: Any clue ? I'm quite lost..

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to debug the API and specify more detail to help narrow down a cause. A couple of things I can see:

```
var prestation = queryString.FirstOrDefault();
// Handle when prestation comes back #null. Is that valid?

var results = db.Partenaires.Where(p => p.PartenairePrestations.Any(pp => pp.Prestation.NomPrestation == prestation.Value))
//                .ToList() // Avoid .ToList() here... Select the entity properties you need.
    .Select(p => new PartenaireMapItem {
        IdPartenaire = p.IdPartenaire,
        FirstName = p.FirstName,
        LastName = p.LastName,
        // NomComplet = p.LastName.Substring(0,1).ToUpper() + ". " + p.FirstName, // Remove. Make this a computed property in your view model.
        Type = p.Type,
        // DureeMin = 50, // Can remove, can be a computed property.
        Lat = p.Lat,
        Lng = p.Lng,
        ImageUrl = p.ImageUrl,
        SeDeplace = p.SeDeplace, // Ok if a String/value. 
        ADomicile = p.ADomicile, // Ok if a String/value.

        Notes = p.NoteClientPartenaires, // Ok if a String/value.
        Prestations = p.PartenairePrestations.Select(y => y.Prestation.NomPrestation).ToList(); // Assuming this is retrieving the names of presentations. List<string>.
    }).ToList();

return results;
```

The early .ToList() was required because you were attempting to compute values (NameComplet) in the Linq expression that normally would have been fed to EF which your DB provider will not understand. For efficiency, only select mapped properties, and instead change any computed values to read-only properties on your view model. (PartenaireMapItem)

```
private string _nomComplet = null;
public string NomComplet
{ 
    get { return _nomComplet ?? (_nomComplet = LastName.Substring(0,1).ToUpper() + ". " + FirstName); }
}
```

That example buffers the result assuming that the name details are read-only. If First/Last name can be updated, just return the calculated name each time.

The other properties should be fine, assuming that SeDeclace/ADomicile are string values and not child entities. The same goes for the list of Prestations. A list of strings for the Prestation names should be fine.

The other minor change I made was to retrieve the view models in a variable to inspect prior to returning. This better facilitates using a breakpoint to inspect the results before returning. From here determine if any error is coming back from the computation of the results, or something else such as serializing the resulting view models back to the client.